# Fragment in Android unnecessarily repeating more than once

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, layout

Iam trying to keep a simple fragment with only one button.But it is coming 2 times like this

[image: This is the image]

I had a linear layout and another nested linear layout in it.These are all present in activity_welcome.xml whose content is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.acs.AfterLogin.WelcomeActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/replacable_container"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Iam trying to replace the replacable_container(Linear Layout) with the fragment whose java class is this :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.acs.AfterLogin.WelcomeActivity;
import com.acs.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;



public class WelcomeFragment1 extends Fragment{

    View v;
    CardView cardView1,cardView2,cardView3;
    CircleImageView userIcon;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The xml content of fragment is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e0ebe5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The operations like fragment transcation and all are contained in the mainactivity whose java code is this :

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.acs.AfterLogin.WelcomeFragments.WelcomeFragment1;
import com.acs.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    WelcomeFragment1 frag1;
    FragmentManager manager;
    String imageUri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        (new FragTask()).execute();
    }
    private class FragTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            frag1 = new WelcomeFragment1();
            transaction.replace(R.id.replacable_container, frag1, "welcome_1");
            transaction.commit();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to replace fragments in an AsyncTask

Comment: Its saying skipped 200 frames !! so I'm afraid

Comment: I think you are inflating the fragment twice. First where you put it into you `v` variable and in the `return`.

Comment: I used v to identify layout items like buttons etc

Comment: put return `v` remove rest line;

Comment: plz give me a sec..

Comment: use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: does it make any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please return inflated view instead of inflating again in return statement.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container);
 return v;
}
```

Comment: exactly the same as we said in comments -.-

Comment: Could you please explain why it happened like that ? Since I'm just inflating and assigning to a variable but how could it show impact on the layout ?

Comment: @Ivan yes its exactly same thanks for your suggestion

Comment: inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container) - this statement will inflate and attach your layout to root layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line

```
v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container);
```

to

```
v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment_1,container, false);
```

And return the inflated view. The boolean value indicates that you don't want to attach your view to container. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)). Fragment will attach it later by itself.